# Can windows 8 store apps be backed up on external HDD?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, windows-store-app

I'm a guy who lives in fear of HDD crashes and thus I like to make a nice backup of pretty much everything on an external HDD. I'm using Windows 8.1 on a desktop PC and windows store apps have me stuck. While I know that some stuff IS backed up online using my Microsoft account,  the actual apps are not.

Suppose I format my hard drive for whatever reason, and am copying back my data. **So for getting back the windows store apps, do I really have to download them again?** While it's not a problem with smaller apps, I have some games (Asphalt 8, Minion Rush, FIFA 14 etc.) which are well over a gigabyte in file size and I'd much rather copy paste them from somewhere than download them again. My internet speed isn't exactly *fast*. I do know where exactly are they kept and have taken ownership of that folder. This is my plan-

1. Copy the 'gigabyte-sized' data to external HDD.
2. Do my usual format, OS reinstall, refresh, reset whatever.
3. Later, open windows store again and set the apps to install again through my online account.
4. Pause them, go to the respective directory and copy-paste in the backed up data.
5. Go back to the store, so basically I'm fooling it into thinking the download was completed. (ya I know this might really mess up the software versions)

My basic aim is to not **download** stuff again and just copy-paste it back. Is there some way to do this? Or something else perhaps?

Comment: Try it.  Use one of the free Windows 8.1 VMS that Microsoft offers, they work with Virtual Box, VMWare, and Hyper-V, transfer the files to the VM and see if it works.

Comment: Why not just use Windows Backup's Image backup and image the entire drive?

Answer (score 1):

Backing up apps isn't straight forward. Each app will consist of at least one folder, its files, plus permissions on those, and then potentially some related registry entries, and shortcuts. Some apps may also install or require some additional components. These components might be installed elsewhere on the system; realistically you have no way of knowing if or where and how to back *those* up too.

If you're after a "baseline" disaster-recovery strategy, use a *sector-based* backup tool to copy your OS drive, sector-for-sector, to a USB hard drive. I've done this before, and it works well, but these days I hardly bother, I just backup my "content", but not apps, to USB key or the Cloud.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps:

4. In C:\Program Files\WindowsApps, ] + A > [Ctrl] + C
5. Click on desktop > Right Click > New > Compressed Zipped Folder > Open it > press [Ctrl] + V > Wait.
6. Move ZIP to Ext. HDD.

If you need to put it back, do 1 - 3 above THEN do this:

1. Move all files to C:\Program Files\WindowsApps
2. Overwrite all other files if asked.

Comment: Ouch, this won't work well. File/folder permissions are lost in the archiving process, and registry entries + Start shortcuts are not backed up using this method.

Comment: Oh and I forgot, any dependencies won't be backed up via this method either. Apps might install or require additional components, which may be installed who-knows-where on the system, and those components will also have registry entries. I'm afraid this solution is just asking for trouble.

Comment: As a matter of fact this can work if you use n external OS however, copying this does only copies the file probably copying packages in %App-Data% might work

Comment: Obviously this answer is more a guesswork than a tried-and-proven method. Misha256 objections seems very serious.

Answer (score -2):

Well you could try copying the thing's in "%App-Data%\Local\Packages" - which contains your present data
However if some error occurred and you override the file might not work as the app may have some check preventing it. Usually the store or Microsoft has your Data backed up.
Also the apps run on app environment, whilst you will have just the files.

Comment: Guesswork, wrong path, not paying attention to the question... this reply is try to break the record of the worst answer ever given.